# If the tree roots must be reduced, is it wise to reduce the crown too?

Tags: pruning, tree-care, roots, root-pruning

Let's say a driveway must be dug in the vicinity (but not closer than 1m) of a large tree (in my case it is a Juglans regia, but I would like the question, and possible answers, to be as generic as possible). This means that certain portion of the tree roots must be removed, inevitably.

Is it wise to do at the same time certain crown pruning too, with reasoning to keep the balance between the roots and the crown?

Comment: 1 meter is very close, for a large tree. In many cases I've seen a tree that was left through some major work like this die within a few years.

Comment: @Ecnerwal If it dies, so be it. But my question is about what can be done so that it can endure the stress under such cicrcumstances.

Comment: You can get paving that allows water to run through it so maybe that's an option .. though that area won't end up as even as the rest of the driveway.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Yes, thanks for hint. I do plan only gravel-type driveway (textile that allows water flow + coarse gravel + fine gravel), I believe that would allow water running down...

Comment: Something like this http://sistemaplastics.com/products/garden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say: no. The tree will regulate itself, maybe with a less growth next summer.  If you will remove a lot of roots, on all sides, the things are different.

But check also the stability of the tree. If you remove the roots on one side (1 meter is very near), the tree could be unbalanced on the other side (e.g. strong winds, especially on the dig side).

Note: it depends also if you remove just the roots in "surface" (1 meter depth) or also in deep.